# `torch.gather` without unbroadcasting

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

I have some batched input `x` of shape `[batch, time, feature]`, and some batched indices `i` of shape `[batch, new_time]` which I want to gather into the time dim of `x`. As output of this operation I want a tensor `y` of shape `[batch, new_time, feature]` with values like this:

```
y[b, t', f] = x[b, i[b, t'], f]
```

In Tensorflow, I can accomplish this by using the [`batch_dims: int` argument of `tf.gather`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather): `y = tf.gather(x, i, axis=1, batch_dims=1)`.

In PyTorch, I can think of some functions which do similar things:

1. [`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.gather.html) of course, but this does not have an argument similar to Tensorflow's `batch_dims`. The output of `torch.gather` will always have the same shape as the indices. So I would need to unbroadcast the `feature` dim into `i` before passing it to `torch.gather`.
2. [`torch.index_select`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.index_select.html), but here, the indices must be one-dimensional. So to make it work I would need to unbroadcast `x` to add a "`batch * new_time`" dim, and then after `torch.index_select` reshape the output.
3. [`torch.nn.functional.embedding`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.embedding.html). Here, the embedding matrices would correspond to `x`. But this embedding function does not support the weights to be batched, so I run into the same issue as for `torch.index_select` (looking at the code, [`tf.embedding` uses `torch.index_select` under the hood](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/b85568a54a9c60986235ad1e0cc5dffc71b9d5b1/aten/src/ATen/native/Embedding.cpp#L14)).

**Is it possible to accomplish such gather operation without relying on unbroadcasting which is inefficient for large dims?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually the most frequent case: when input and index tensors don't perfectly match the number of dimensions. You can still utilize [`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.gather.html) though since you can rewrite your expression:

```
y[b, t, f] = x[b, i[b, t], f]
```

as:

```
y[b, t, f] = x[b, i[b, t, f], f]
```

which ensures all three tensors have an equal number of dimensions. This reveals a third dimension on `i`, which we can easily create *for free* by unsqueezing a dimension and expanding it to the shape of `x`. You can do so with `i[:,None].expand_as(x)`.

Here is a minimal example:

```
>>> b = 2; t = 3; f = 1
>>> x = torch.rand(b, t, f)
>>> i = torch.randint(0, t, (b, f))

>>> x.gather(1, i[:,None].expand_as(x))
```

Comment: Oh cool, I did not know `torch.expand` existed and that it does not actually allocate any memory. Then what I referred to as "unbroadcasting" in my above post is actually not a problem. Thanks!